# Apply function to a list of columns in a loop and output dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a function that is set up like this:

```
def function(df, apply_col, static_col):
    do something
    return df

#calling the function
df = function(df, 'col_a', 'st_col')
```

This works fine. But, I want to apply this function to a list of columns by name. I tried something like this:

```
col_list = ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'....'col_n']

for i in list:
    df = function(df, i, 'st_col')
```

I get a `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I would like to apply this function to a dataframe in a loop with the static column staying the same and returning a resulting dataframe with all the columns having the function applied to them. Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with the line `for i in list:` Since list is defined as a python object it should read `for i in col_list:`

Comment: This was a bad mistake, thanks for catching. It works now!